# How to get the unique values in nested 2d array based on specific index in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, group-by, ruby-on-rails-5, unique-constraint

How can I get a unique 2d nested array based on a specific index of that 2d array?

Basically, I want to show the unique names that belong to a certain associated model, in the dropdown list. Here is what the query looks like

```
Product.where(live: true).includes(:primary_concern).map{|q| [q.primary_concern.name, q.id]}
```

but it returns all the names while I want only unique names to show in the dropdown list.

I tried to use rails group by, but it is throwing undefined table error because **primary_concern** is not a model itself, its an association to a model let say **concern**, with a different foerign_key name

Comment: Can you show the models?

Comment: Yes, uniq(&:first) is what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Product.where(live: true).includes(:primary_concern).map{|q| [q.primary_concern.name, q.id]}.uniq(&:first)
```